# How to active background color in color sector in admin dashboard while admin clicks on menu it goes to default set background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

The image shows admin panel color selector to change background color of header, lo and menu bar. When User clicks on particular color it set but when user clicks on menus then it goes to default color set. It does not activate user selected background color. This page is in asp .net [image]

```
<div id="styleSelector">
        <div class="selector-toggle">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p class="selector-title">Style Selector</p>
            </li>
            <li class="theme-option">
                <span class="sub-title">Header BG Color Option</span>
                <div id="theme-color">
                    <a href="#" class="header-bg" hoe-color-type="header-bg1">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="header-bg" hoe-color-type="header-bg2">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="header-bg" hoe-color-type="header-bg3">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="header-bg" hoe-color-type="header-bg4">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="header-bg" hoe-color-type="header-bg5">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="header-bg" hoe-color-type="header-bg6">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="header-bg" hoe-color-type="header-bg7">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="header-bg" hoe-color-type="header-bg8">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="header-bg" hoe-color-type="header-bg9">&nbsp;</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="theme-option">
                <span class="sub-title">Left Panel BG Color Option</span>
                <div id="theme-color">
                    <a href="#" class="lpanel-bg" hoe-color-type="lpanel-bg1">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="lpanel-bg" hoe-color-type="lpanel-bg2">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="lpanel-bg" hoe-color-type="lpanel-bg3">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="lpanel-bg" hoe-color-type="lpanel-bg4">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="lpanel-bg" hoe-color-type="lpanel-bg5">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="lpanel-bg" hoe-color-type="lpanel-bg6">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="lpanel-bg" hoe-color-type="lpanel-bg7">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="lpanel-bg" hoe-color-type="lpanel-bg8">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="lpanel-bg" hoe-color-type="lpanel-bg9">&nbsp;</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="theme-option">
                <span class="sub-title">Logo Color BG Option</span>
                <div id="theme-color">
                    <a href="#" class="logo-bg" hoe-color-type="logo-bg1">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="logo-bg" hoe-color-type="logo-bg2">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="logo-bg" hoe-color-type="logo-bg3">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="logo-bg" hoe-color-type="logo-bg4">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="logo-bg" hoe-color-type="logo-bg5">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="logo-bg" hoe-color-type="logo-bg6">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="logo-bg" hoe-color-type="logo-bg7">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="logo-bg" hoe-color-type="logo-bg8">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="logo-bg" hoe-color-type="logo-bg9">&nbsp;</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="theme-option">
                <span class="sub-title">Theme Background BG Option</span>
                <div id="theme-color">
                    <a href="#" class="theme-bg" hoe-themebg-type="bg1">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="theme-bg" hoe-themebg-type="bg2">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="theme-bg" hoe-themebg-type="bg3">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="theme-bg" hoe-themebg-type="bg4">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="theme-bg" hoe-themebg-type="bg5">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="theme-bg" hoe-themebg-type="bg6">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="theme-bg" hoe-themebg-type="bg7">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="theme-bg" hoe-themebg-type="bg8">&nbsp;</a>
                    <a href="#" class="theme-bg" hoe-themebg-type="bg9">&nbsp;</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="theme-option">
                <span class="sub-title">Theme Layout</span>
                <select id="theme-layout" class="form-control minimal input-sm">
                    <option name="theme-layout" value="wide-layout">Wide Layout</option>
                    <option name="theme-layout" value="box-layout">Boxed Layout</option> 
                </select>
            </li>
            <li class="theme-option">
                <span class="sub-title">SideBar Effect</span>
                <select id="leftpanel-effect" class="form-control minimal input-sm">
                    <option name="lpanel-effect" value="shrink">Default</option>
                    <option name="lpanel-effect" value="overlay">Overlay</option>
                    <option name="lpanel-effect" value="push">Push</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li class="theme-option">
                <span class="sub-title">Navigation Type</span>
                <select id="navigation-type" class="form-control minimal input-sm">
                    <option name="navigation-type" value="vertical">Vertical</option>
                    <option name="navigation-type" value="vertical-compact">Vertical Compact</option>
                    <option name="navigation-type" value="horizontal">Horizontal</option>
                    <option name="navigation-type" value="horizontal-compact">Horizontal compact</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li class="theme-option">
                <span class="sub-title">Navigation Side</span>
                <select id="navigation-side" class="form-control minimal input-sm">
                    <option name="navigation-side" value="leftside">Left</option>
                    <option name="navigation-side" value="rightside">Right</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li class="theme-option">
                <span class="sub-title">Sidebar Position</span>
                <select id="sidebar-position" class="form-control minimal input-sm">
                    <option name="sidebar-position" value="default">Default</option>
                    <option name="sidebar-position" value="fixed">Fixed</option>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question.

Comment: Here is the code for color selector...

Comment: /*Header Background Color start*/

#theme-color a[hoe-color-type="header-bg1"] {
    background: #70ca63;
} ......upto 9 background color

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the colors to be remembered, you'll have to store the color selections in a data store somewhere, maybe a database.
I cannot see the back-end of this application nor the Javascript handling the color selection so there isn't much to go with.

Comment: Here is the code for color selector.../*Header Background Color start*/

#theme-color a[hoe-color-type="header-bg1"] {
    background: #70ca63;
} ......upto 9 background color